# Using IdentityServer4 with F5 Load Balancer

Tags: identityserver4

I’m facing a problem with IdentityServer4 installed in multiple servers for load balancing. The problem is that clients/users get invalid tokens exception every time the load balancer switches to another IdentityServer4 Server. Which makes sense, since the next IdentityServer4 in line did not issue the token in question.

The obvious solution is to store the tokens in a Database shared with all IdentityServer4-Servers. However, I have not been able to find any information on how to validate incoming tokens against a database or any other storage type for that matter. It appears that the IdentityServer4 validates the incoming tokens from clients/users under the hood, and I couldn’t find any extension for it.
I’m able to store the tokens in a database, but how do I validate tokens from a database via a custom extension or whatever?

Can someone please help with this issue? Am I missing something? Is there another way of load balancing IdentityServer4?

Comment: Have you setup aspnet core data protection to use the same shared storage across all IS4 deployed instances? I'm assuming here also that they are all connecting to the same database for the PersistedGrant dbcontext?

Comment: I have not setup aspnet core data protection. I assume in the ConfigureServices method of the Startup class, I could do something like this:

services.AddDataProtection()

But how do I configure the data protection? I don’t see any option for database or data store. Do I need to install IdentityServer4.Storage?

Comment: Yes, all instances are connected to the same database. But, I have not been able to store anything to the PersistedGrants table. I implemented the IPersistedGrantStore extension but it never hits any method, not when requesting a token or when calling a protected API. I did register the extension like this
 
services.AddPersistedGrantStore<PersistedGrantStore>()

in the ConfigureServices method. I’m at a complete loss. Maybe some code samples would help.

Comment: As per IS4 documentation [here](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/crypto.html#data-protection) you will need to setup a common storage for aspnet core data protection so that cookie cryptography is consistent across all instances. The link will also offer a [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview?view=aspnetcore-3.1) to Microsoft's documentation for how to set this up.  You can use Azure Blob Storage, or even an EFCore DbContext.  Just not local file system which is the default if you don't set anything.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I think I can get at least a step further now. I got pulled into something else today, so I'll try to work on it in the next days and will let you know how far i got.